# Since we have the virtrual memory technique, why can’t the application use 4GB memory on the 32-bit OS?

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system

I wonder why the application can't use 4GB memory on the 32-bit OS since we use the virtrual memory technique. I know some programs like OS which should use some memory, does it mean every application must treat these programs such OS as a part of them from the point of 4 GB addressable virtrual memory.

Answer (score 0):

1. The OS or hardware divide the address space into special purposes. E.g., Kernel and User. The logical address range assigned to these other purposes cannot be used by the application.
2. System Parameters can limit the size of the address space.
3. Quotas can limit the logical address space for a specific user or process.
4. Page file space can limit the logical address space for everyone.

Comment: Improvement: The addressable range is still "only" 32 bits. Now, if the OS needs to reserve some parts of that addressable range for things such as memory mapped I/O devices, an application by definition can't have access to a full 32-bits address range, since part of that range is reserved for the OS.
There are hardware tricks to increase the addressable range, such as [Physical Address Extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#Physical_Address_Extension_.28PAE.29), although I don't know if they are widely used by OSs.

Comment: Such hardware tricks were common in the days of 16-bit processors.